# How to get a specific style for a particular page from Site.css?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

In following code in Site.css asp.net Mvc 4 C#.

```
.Content
{
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

I want to use this code in all of my application. But I want to omit padding-top for a particular page. How can I do this?

When I use .Content class in that page. By default _layout.cshtml get .content from site.css

Comment: The order of applying css formatting is *inline* > *in-document* > *external file*. `site.css` is an external file.

Comment: Thanks, I know this but not works when _layout.cshtml override this.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel  It is sort out. Yes you are correct. If I make padding-top: 0px; in document it's works. but If I delete this line  in documents, It takes padding-top from _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Content
{
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

If I use like this in the view page, It Override the .Content class in _layout.cshtml. But If I didn't mention about padding like follows It takes from _layout.cshtml.

.Content
    {
        min-height: 500px;
    }

Answer (score 1):

How about creating you own class and using it

```
.Contents
{
    min-height: 500px;

}
```

Comment: This not works. Because _layout.cshtml page get that .Contents class from site.css

Comment: It's work when I use like follows                                          .Content
{
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}